# Fiddler adding line breaks and hex

Tags: json, hex, fiddler, invalid-characters

Does anyone know why I would be experiencing line breaks and HEX in the raw output of a JSON response in Fiddler?

Here's a segment and you can see from the image that several lines new lines are inserted preceded by hex.

Is this the result of some kind of buffering? If so how would I disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is called HTTP `Chunked` [Transfer-Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). In most cases, it's not Fiddler that does it, it's the server. You can remove the encoding using the `Transformer` tab or the `Decode` toggle in Fiddler's toolbar.